# using get on a dictionary of 2^n numbers each made up of n 0's or 1's by only looking at a single element of the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary such as:

```
mylist={'000' :1,
        '001' :1,
        '010':2,
        '011':2,
        '100' :1,
        '101' :1,
        '110':2,
        '111':2,}
```

I want to know how many times '1' is the first element of the dictionary. I can do

```
mylist.get('100')+mylist.get('111')+mylist.get('110')+mylist.get('101')
```

but this becomes quite inefficient as I add more elements to my dictionary. Is there any way I can search for this efficiently for example something like

```
mylist.get('1xx')
```

Comment: which language is that?

Comment: I was just writing this on jupyter notebook, so python

Comment: Noted and corrected

Comment: John, this is true but I want to total the numbers besides this. E.g in this case it is 6

Comment: 6 or 4? I'm not sure about what you want.

Comment: I want 6 in this case, 1+1+2+2=6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple generator expression:

```
sum(v for k,v in mydict.items() if k.startswith('1'))
```

evaluates to `6`.

(since it is a dictionary, calling it `mylist` sounded too odd, so I changed it).

Comment: Thanks John. How does this generalise if I want to find the second element for example? (Or ideally any element)

Comment: @LOC `sum(v for k,v in mydict.items() if k[1] == '1')`. You could also use  `itertools.product` to generate just the keys that you want, though that would involve a bit more code.